# php error ( Call to a member function query() on resource )

Tags: php

```
<?php
$dbhost='localhost:3306';
$dbuser='root';
$dbpass='';
$con=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if(!$con) {
die("Couldnotconnect:".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('shop');
$sql="SELECTCD_ID,Title,Artist,Year,Company,Price,Quantity,TypeFROMcd_data";
$result=$con->query($sql); //somethingiswronghere
$numRows=$result->num_rows; //somethingiswronghere
if($result->num_rows) { //somethingiswronghere
//outputdataofeachrow

//somethingiswronghere
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  echo"id:".$row["CD_ID"]."Name:".$row["Title"]."".$row["Artist"].$row["Year"].$row["Company"].$row["Price"]."Euro".$row["Quantity"].$row["Type"];
}
}
else {
  echo"0results";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: _Warning_
This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: You are using `mysql_*` for database connection and fetching records in `mysqli_*` which will not work.

Comment: your sql is wrong `"SELECT CD_ID,Title,Artist,Year,Company,Price,Quantity,TypeFROMcd_data";`

Comment: What does mean the **somethingiswronghere**?

Comment: Your question content is very poor..!

Comment: The site doesn't let me to put the entire text as code thats why i wrote that ... i am new user in this site

Comment: please instead of criticize my question content and other stuff can you help me by giving me the solution with code?

Comment: its better to help him, or mark as duplicate, instead of criticize

Comment: @hellfireworld: check the example that i have shared in answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many issues in your code:

1. You want to use mysqli_* but using mysql_* functions. You can't mix both.
2. Your query is not looking good.

`SELECTCD_ID,Title,Artist,Year,Company,Price,Quantity,TypeFROMcd_data`

I think your query should be like this:

```
SELECT CD_ID,Title,Artist,Year,Company,Price,Quantity,Type FROM cd_data
```

Here is the complete example of your code by using **MYSQLi Object Oriented**:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT CD_ID,Title,Artist,Year,Company,Price,Quantity,Type FROM cd_data";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //your stuff
    }    
} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man you save me :)...  my query spaces was edited by the site (SELECT CD_ID...) it was the same as you wrote it. But all the the other code was wrong :P . It works great!